# How to set MaxItemsInObjectGraph programmatically

Tags: wcf

This is how I am configuring the client from code

```
    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
    binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;

    binding.MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
    binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = Int32.MaxValue;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = Int32.MaxValue;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = Int32.MaxValue;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = Int32.MaxValue;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = Int32.MaxValue;


    BnsApiClient client = new BnsApiClient(binding, new EndpointAddress("http://mysite/Hello.svc"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How can I set the maxItemsInObjectGraph property programmatically from a Silverlight Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473620/how-can-i-set-the-maxitemsinobjectgraph-property-programmatically-from-a-silverli)