# maxItemsInObjectGraph in asp.net web service?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

A client of ours is using an asp.net web service (asmx) I created and is getting an error saying the maxItemsInObjectGraph is too small. I told him to make the necessary changes in his app.config file. But where do I have to make these changes on my side?? The web.config file in my web service doesn't mention maxItemsInObjectGraph.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you sure it's an asmx service?  I only know maxItemsInObjectGraph from WCF.

Comment: Hmm, did they create a WCF based client?

Comment: I didn't know you could choose.

Comment: It's Add Web Reference | Add Service Reference

Comment: Yes but where can they choose if it's WCF based or not? All I do normally is put in the URL with the asmx extension (svc extension for WCF) and click GO.

Answer (score 1):

Because it has a default value which is used when it's not in your config. You'll have to either add it to your web.config or to your code as shown [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/148523.aspx), [here](http://thedotnethub.blogspot.de/2009/10/passing-large-messages-in-wcf.html), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298209/how-to-fix-maxitemsinobjectgraph-error) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473620/how-can-i-set-the-maxitemsinobjectgraph-property-programmatically-from-a-silverl).

EDIT: For ASMX there isn't a setting for maxItemsInObjectGraph, setting the maximum request length might help though.

```
<location path="yourservice.asmx">
 <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" />
 </system.web>
</location>
```

Other properties for the [httpRuntime on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't make a difference. Any other suggestions?